# Passing state from async call to child class in React

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, axios

Need some advice on using `Axios` call for fetching data and setting it in `state` for `render`ing some other component. Here’s the problem:

```
class Main{
    componentDidMount(){
        Axios.get(...).then(res=> this.setState(var1))
        Axios.get(...).then(res=> this.setState(var2))
    }
    render(){
        const {var1, var2} = this.state;
        return !var1 && !var2 ? 'Loading...' : <replace_this>
    }
}
```

**Case 1:**  with ‘Loaded’

Output: I see Loaded and also console.log prints the variable values

**Case 2:**  with `<Sub var1={var1} var2={var2} />`

Error:

- Main: Can’t perform a React state update on an unmounted component
- Sub: Can’t read property of null (var1 or var2)

How do I resolve Case 2?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for your time. The conditional checked required `||` instead of `&&`.